# How to convert Ruby Regular Expression into PCRE

Tags: ruby, regex, pcre

I want to rewrite some ruby code into c/c++ code, so I want to use a regular expression library implemented in c. it seems that PCRE is a good choice. there are many ruby style regular expressions. how can i convert it into PCRE style automatically.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of such "Ruby Regular Expressions" that can't be just copied and used as PCRE in c/c++ code?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Ruby actually uses PCRE.

Comment: @p11y the current MRI Ruby uses [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo). I don’t think earlier version used PCRE — other implementations might.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby [regular expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) are [`PCRE`](http://www.pcre.org/) regular expressions as PCRE stands for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions and defines a particular syntax for the regular expressions it supports.

For help on individual PCRE regex features see the second article I linked to and for ruby specific methods see the first (as you will see, the syntax of the actual regex's used are the same)

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments the regex engine used by ruby is [`Onigmo`](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) which according to the linked to page has some of the new features of Perl 5.10. PCRE is a regex library and "The current implementation of PCRE corresponds approximately with Perl 5.12" so there may be some discrepancies around the edges. The syntax is largely the same though, look through the Onigmo github page and ruby api dock to see the difference. By and large though it is probably safe to assume that most regexes that you translate from ruby to PCRE will work without problems.

Comment: PCRE is a specific regex library. The current MRI Ruby uses the [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) regex engine. Whilst the two engines may share many feature they are not the same.

Comment: @matt I was under the impression that Onigmo was PCRE compliant?

Comment: The PCRE man page says it uses “the same syntax and semantics as Perl, with just a few differences” and that “there  is  some  support for one or two .NET and Oniguruma syntax items” (Onigmo is a fork of Onigurama). The Onigmo readme says “Some of new features introduced in Perl 5.10+ can be used”. They are probably broadly compatible, but there will be differences around the edges, especially with the more advanced and obscure featues. My point is that PCRE is a library, not a specification, and Ruby doesn’t use it.

Comment: @matt Good point, also in the PCRE page it says "The  current implementation of PCRE corresponds approximately with Perl 5.12" so Onigmo is a couple of point releases behind. I will edit my answer to include this information, thanks for pointing it out. Let me know if you think anything else should be added/changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is one Ruby construct that might cause problems: `#{code}`

This can be used inside a regular expression and it will be replaced by the result of the code (as in double quoted strings).

One example: `"dideldideldummdummdumm".match(/didel#{'dumm'*2}/)`